# Problems with has_many through Association Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

So i'm trying to do a database that stores the current weather:

```
 --------------             ------------------            ----------
|              | 1       * |                  |*       1 |          | 
| YearMonthDay |-----------| WeatherCondition |----------| Location |
|              |           |                  |          |          |
 --------------             ------------------            ----------
```

I generated models using belongs_to and has_many :through

```
class WeatherCondition < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :year_month_day
    belongs_to :location
end

class YearMonthDay < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :weather_conditions
    has_many :locations, :through => :weather_conditions
 end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :weather_conditions
    has_many :year_month_days, :through => :weather_conditions
end
```

And also created a migration for each of them, the YearMonthDay and the Locations ones are just normal and the WeatherConditions is as follows:

```
class CreateWeatherConditions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :weather_conditions do |t|
        t.belongs_to :location, index: true
        t.belongs_to :year_month_day, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, but I am getting an error:

```
 unknown attribute 'year_month_day_id' for WeatherCondition.
```

Comment: Looking at your pastebin models, you do not need a many to many relationship. You need one to one relationship between date-weather-location, where weather is dependent on date and location. If no-one else answers this, I will amend my answer later tonight.

Comment: PS. your models are lacking foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to add the foreign keys to WeatherConditions:

If you are creating a new table:

```
class CreateWeatherConditions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :weather_conditions do |t|
        t.integer :location_id
        t.integer :year_month_day_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

If you already have the table:

```
class CreateWeatherConditions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :weather_conditions, :location_id, :integer
    add_column :weather_conditions, :year_month_day_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: that didn't made sense to me :/

Comment: can you explain what doesn't make sense?

Comment: you have two ifs in your sentence, can you detail a bit more?

Comment: use one or the other depending on if you already have the table or not.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is particular about plural tables. It may not understand how to pluralize year_month_day. What does your schema look like?

Comment: @ManoelRibeiro, I'm confused, that pastebin shows that you already have a weather_conditions table. Do you want to add the location and year_month_day id?

Comment: Do I have to add it? I thought this ID came when I had the has_many thing

Comment: you have to add it. the has_many thing does not affect the schema, only migration does

Comment: Instead of the create table, just drop in two add_columns

Comment: im following exactly what is said in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Creating a many to many relationship, you need a has_and_belongs_to_many notation.

```
class YearMonthDay < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :year_month_days
end
```

Drop the class for WeatherConditions, you only need the join table which has to be named to match the two models. The names have to be in alphabetical order.

```
create_table :locations_year_month_days, id: false do |t|
    t.belongs_to :location, index: true
    t.belongs_to :year_month_day, index: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Once you have relationship working, you can then call my_date.locations to get an array of location objects tied to that date, or my_location.year_month_dates for vice versa.

This [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) has a longer explanation.

Comment: You can also have as I did but with through, look in the same guide!

Comment: Yes, but as you have found it is far more complex and error prone.

Comment: I need attributes in between though :/